# How to mark messages as read using gmail api as i parse?

Tags: python, gmail-api

In python how do i mark messages as 'read' as i parse it from gmail api ?
Also how do i save the values to the database after parsing?
This is the code so far to get the content of each message.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import httplib2
import os
import re
import MySQLdb
from email.utils import parsedate_tz,mktime_tz,formatdate
from requests.adapters import HTTPAdapter
import datetime
from datetime import date,timedelta
import time
from apiclient import discovery
import oauth2client
from oauth2client import client
from oauth2client import tools
import json
try:
    import argparse
    flags = argparse.ArgumentParser(parents=[tools.argparser]).parse_args()
except ImportError:
    flags = None
SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly'
CLIENT_SECRET_FILE = 'client_server.json'
APPLICATION_NAME = 'Gmail API Python Quickstart'
def get_credentials():

    home_dir = os.path.expanduser('~')
    credential_dir = os.path.join(home_dir, '.credentials')
    if not os.path.exists(credential_dir):
        os.makedirs(credential_dir)
    credential_path = os.path.join(credential_dir,
                                   'gmail-python-quickstart.json')

    store = oauth2client.file.Storage(credential_path)
    credentials = store.get()
    if not credentials or credentials.invalid:
        flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets(CLIENT_SECRET_FILE, SCOPES)
        flow.user_agent = APPLICATION_NAME
        if flags:
            credentials = tools.run_flow(flow, store, flags)
        else: # Needed only for compatibility with Python 2.6
            credentials = tools.run(flow, store)
        print('Storing credentials to ' + credential_path)
    return credentials

def main():

    da=date.fromordinal(730920)
    credentials = get_credentials()
    http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())
    service = discovery.build('gmail', 'v1', http=http)
    today=date.today()
    print (today)
    yesterday=today-timedelta(1)
    print (yesterday) 
    response = service.users().messages().list(userId='me',q='in:inbox is:unread newer_than:1d').execute()
    messages=[]
    store=[]
    message1=[]
    test2=[]
    da=[]
    if 'messages' in response:
     messages.extend(response['messages'])
    fo = open("fooa.txt", "wb") 
    for i in range(len(messages)):
     store=messages[i]['id']
     message = service.users().messages().get(userId='me',id=store,format='metadata',metadataHeaders=['from','date']).execute()
     fo.write(message['snippet'].encode('utf-8')+"")
     From=message['payload']['headers'][0]['value']
     fo.write(From+"");
     da=message['payload']['headers'][1]['value']
     fo.write(da+"\n");
     for line in open("fooa.txt"):
      print(line)
    fo.close()
    a=open("fooa.txt","r")
    for wo in a:
     match=re.findall(r':[\w]+',wo)
     for word in match:
      print(word.replace(':',' '))
    db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","testuser","mysql23","db1" )
    cursor = db.cursor()
   sql = """INSERT INTO customers((LeadName, CITY, SERVICE,CUSTOMER, MOBILE, EMAIL)
         VALUES (, , , , )"""
try:
   cursor.execute(sql)
   db.commit()
except:
   db.rollback()
    db.close()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Need help please!

Answer (score 11):

You need to [modify](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/modify) the message in a separate request, and remove the `UNREAD`-label.

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages/1533cb4d7dac1633/modify?access_token={ACCESS_TOKEN}

{
 "removeLabelIds": [
  "UNREAD"
 ]
}
```

Comment: i am getting a permission insufficient error...because initially i had given readonly permission...what do i do ?

Answer (score 10):

If you're trying to mark the message as read, you will have to do something like:

```
gmail_service
       .users()
       .messages()
       .modify(userId='me', id=message_id, body={'removeLabelIds': ['UNREAD']})
       .execute()
```

Answer (score 2):

What you can do with the Gmail API depends on what scope you've granted OAuth. Here's what you need to do:

1. Change `SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly'` to this:

```
SCOPES = [
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify'
]
```

Explanation: since marking an email as "unread" is a message modification, you need the 'gmail.modify' scope in order to use this API request. To see the full list of scopes, refer to [Choose Auth Scopes](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/auth/scopes).

2. Delete your `token.pickle` file and rerun the script. You'll need to do this in order to reauthorize the OAuth app with the new scopes, which will then generate a new `token.pickle` file.
3. Here's the code to mark an email as read in Python:

```
service.users().messages().modify(userId='me', id=message['id'], body={
    'removeLabelIds': ['UNREAD']
}).execute()
```