# Is there any way of marking an email as read/seen using Gmail's API? Link to the API below

Tags: java, rest, gmail-api

I tried going over the the entire thing, read the Java client reference too, but it doesn't seem that there is a way to do it, which is strange as it is possible to mark an email as read using IMAP wth Gmail.

It seems it's only possible to [add/remove labels from messages](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages/modify)

Can anyone confirm this?

Comment: looking at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35778772/how-to-mark-messages-as-read-using-gmail-api-as-i-parse you should be able to add an `UNREAD` or `READ` label to do this

Comment: Do you want to use the gmail api or IMAP?    If its the gmail api then just remove the label UNREAD

Comment: Oh that's awesome! Will try and get back to report if it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add/remove the `UNREAD` label and it will update the email status. It was already mentioned in the comments by [joshmeranda](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11548057/joshmeranda) and [Linda Lawton - DaImTo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1841839/linda-lawton-daimto) but I wanted to provide a code as an example using Java.

This would update a message using a given messageId by swapping its status from `READ` to `UNREAD` or vice-versa:

```
        String user = "A_USER_ID"; //<- use "me" to use the authenticated user's ID.
        String messageId = "A_MESSAGE_ID";
        Message message = service.users().messages().get(user, messageId).execute();

        if (message.getLabelIds().contains("UNREAD")) {
            ModifyMessageRequest modifyRequest = new ModifyMessageRequest()
                    .setRemoveLabelIds(Arrays.asList(new String[] { "UNREAD" }));
            Message modifiedMessage = service.users().messages().modify(user, messageId, modifyRequest).execute();
        } else {
            ModifyMessageRequest modifyRequest = new ModifyMessageRequest()
                    .setAddLabelIds(Arrays.asList(new String[] { "UNREAD" }));
            Message modifiedMessage = service.users().messages().modify(user, messageId, modifyRequest).execute();
        }
```

---

#### Reference:

- [Gmail API Java Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/java) to get the `Gmail service` object.

Comment: I ended up doing precisely this. Will accept the answer as reference.